# how to use Angular-Component (v1.6.3) with requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, require, angular-components

I am creating a angular application with Components. I am using RequireJs to load the required modules. I am able to use Controllers, directives, services without any issue with requirejs. But Components are not getting loaded. I am not getting any error as well. Below is my code. Am I doing any mistake?

```
define([], function (app) {
    'use strict';

    function securityComponent() {

        return {
            template: '<h1> test</h1/>'
        }
    }

    return securityComponent;
});

   var securityComponent = require('security/security.component');
    var app = angular.module('WLAPP', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

    // Register custom components.

    app.component("securityComponent", securityComponent);

in HTML

<security-component></security-component>
```

Comment: did you bootstrap the application by specifying `ng-app="WLAPP"`?

Comment: Yes. I am bootstrapping manually

Comment: angular.bootstrap(document, ['WLAPP']);